# Liquibase doesn't export correctly indexes which use functions like lower(column)

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

Index:

```
CREATE INDEX guild_name_lower_ops
  ON guilds
  USING btree
  (lower(name::text) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" varchar_pattern_ops);
```

Generated changeset:

```
<changeSet author="Vlad (generated)" id="1450262497286-89">
<createIndex indexName="guild_name_lower_ops" tableName="guilds" /> 
</changeSet>
```

And it doesn't pass "status" command check with "columns is empty" error message.

Why it's not exported? Are there any workarounds so I can still use liquibase with my db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquibase does not currently figure this out for Postgres. The workaround is to alter the XML after it is generated so that when creating new databases, the indexes are created properly.

Comment: Can you please give a short example how this index should be corrected in xml?

Comment: @Vlad have a look on modifySql function http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/modify_sql.html to append "USING btree
  (lower(name::text) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" varchar_pattern_ops)" to generated query